# How to add dependent assembly without editing webConfig?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, .net-assembly, startup

So according to my boss we are not allowed to edit the webConfig (I know weird right?). I've added nuGet packages for Microsoft.Owin and other dependent packages. These packages made changes to the webConfig by dependent assemblies to a runtime node.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      ...etc...
```

My question is can I remove the runtime node and its contents but still have the same functionality without removing or changing code? If I remove the node now I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not allowed to edit the config file?

Comment: @xxbbcc, we have 200+ customers, some we host the application for them and some they host the app themselves. There was an issue before my time where they edited the web config (possibly due to a change in which dotNet framework they were using) and is caused massive failures. Since then they are very very cautious about editing the webConfig. We're not even allowed to check in changes to the webConfig. I've made changes to the config in my branch of the project.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a very poor policy - I feel for you.

Comment: @xxbbcc, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see a `bindingRedirect` element in your application config file, this means that you have some inconsistency between the versions of the assemblies you are using. The NuGet system automatically detects this inconsistency and adds the binding redirect to ensure that at least you don't get compile time errors. Of course at runtime you might have problems with it because the assembly that depends on the older version of `Microsoft.Owin` might not work as expected with the one you are redirecting to: especially if there are some breaking changes and it attempts to call a method that no longer exists. The sole fact that you got a binding redirect added in your config file when installing the NuGet means that you might a problem and this problem might manifest only under certain specific circumstances at runtime.

So basically I would start by looking at all dependent assemblies that are references in this project along with their dependencies and try to see where this inconsistency of the versions come from. Then try to eliminate it by finding a newer version of this assembly that works with the latest `Microsoft.Owin`.

Comment: Could you show me an example of this with a brand new MVC application? If you do _File -> New -> Project_ and create a new **ASP.NET Web Application** with **Individual User Account Authentication**, there are already `bindingRedirect` elements in the webConfig

Comment: If there are already binding redirects in a newly created application then I guess there's something wrong with this application that needs to be fixed. I don't say that the application won't work with them, it's just that there's a risk of getting a runtime error because of those assembly version discrepancies between the dependent assemblies that are being referenced.

Comment: is there a way to set the `bindingRedirect` elements in C# instead of the webConfig? Maybe somethere in Global.asax?